# Prove that the closure of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Quick analysis question along with my attempt. Looking for feedback:

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $E \subset X$.
>
> Prove that the closure of $E$, $\overline{E}$, is closed.

**Proof**: By definition, $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$ where $E'$ is the set of all limit points of $E$. Take all subsequent neighborhoods as open.

Let there be an arbitrary $p \in X$ but $p \notin \overline{E}$. Then $p$ is neither a point of $E$ nor a limit point of $E$. Since $p$ is *not* a limit point of $E$, there exists a neighborhood $N$ centered at $p$ that contains no points of $E$. This implies that $N$ also contains no points of $E'$ since if there were such a point in $E'$, $N$ would be a neighborhood of such a point and thus contain a point in $E$ by definition of limit points, leading to a contradiction.

Thus, we have a neighborhood $N$ for point $p \in \overline{E}^c$ that contains points neither in $E$ nor in $E'$. In other words, $N \subset (E \cup E')^c$, or $N \subset \overline{E}^c$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, we have that every point $p \in \overline{E}^c$ is an interior point. Therefore $\overline{E}^c$ is open by definition. Hence $\overline{E}$ is closed. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I think that be basic arguments you make here are clear and correct. However, the way you wrote down the proof is a bit cumbersome. Practice writing down proofs in a minimal way. Sometimes, books are "too minimal" in the sense that they leave out details, and one has to find a middle course.
Note that it's hard for us to help out here in detail because this trivial statement depends on the way the book defined the basic topological notions, which can be done in different equivalent ways (e.g. you could define the closure as the smallest closed set that contains $E$).

Comment: The proof is correct and in line with how Rudin defines all these concepts. Rudin can be hard with how concise the book is, so I wouldn't worry too much about having to write things out properly sometimes. I feel you will get used to the style as you get better; I also remember being stuck on that proof when I first saw it.

Comment: Thanks Cataline, I appreciate the helpful comment. I do feel fine with Rudin's style, I just wanted to make sure that I'm filling in the details properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing:

$X$ is a metric space, $E \subset X$.

1) $\overline{E}= E \cup E'$.

Show that $\overline {E}$ is closed.

2) Let $p \not \in \overline {E}$, i.e $p \in (\overline{E})^c$.

$p \not \in \overline{E}$ implies:

$p\not \in E$, and $p \not  \in E'$,

a) Since $p \not \in E'$  there is a $B_r (p)$ , a

$r$ - neighbourhood of $p$, with

$B_r(p) \cap E =\emptyset.$

b) Also: $B_r(p) \cap E' =\emptyset $.

Assume the contrary:

There is a $e' \in E'$ with $e' \in B_r(p).$

Consider the ball $B_\epsilon(e')$, where

$\epsilon:= r - ||p,e'|| >0.$

Then $B_\epsilon(e') \subset B_r(p)$.
(Proof uses the triangle inequality).

Since $e' \in E'$,

$B_\epsilon(e') \cap E \not = \emptyset$,

implies $B_r(p) \cap E \not = \emptyset$,

a contradiction.

Hence  $p \in (E \cup E')^c$, and

$B_r(p) \cap (E \cup E') =\emptyset$, i.e.

$B_r(p) \subset (E \cup E')^c$.

$\rightarrow $

$(E \cup E')^c$ open, or $\overline{E}$ closed.